# PHP IMAP-Extension get clean Message-Body

Tags: php, email, imap

I'm just experimenting a little with the IMAP-Extension for PHP and I build the connection using an object like this:

```
function __construct($user, $pass, $server = 'my.mailserver.ch', $port = 143) {
    $this->server = $server;
    $this->user = $user;
    $this->pass = $pass;
    $this->port = $port;

    if($this->conn = imap_open('{'.$this->server.'}', $this->user, $this->pass)){
        $this->success = 1;
    }else{
        $this->success = -1;
    }

    $this->inbox();
}
```

I then use the following function to get the neccessary data from my mails.
(Which works)

```
function inbox() {
    $this->msg_cnt = imap_num_msg($this->conn);
    $in = array();
    for($i = 1; $i <= $this->msg_cnt; $i++) {
        $in[] = array(
            'index'     => $i,
            'header'    => imap_headerinfo($this->conn, $i),
            'body'      => imap_fetchbody($this->conn, $i),
            'structure' => imap_fetchstructure($this->conn, $i)
        );
    }

    $this->inbox = $in;
}
```

But if I now look into the body of the message, I get multiple different things besides the message, like:

```
--001a113ec946082fc705210e59c7 Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=001a113ec946082fc005210e59c5 --001a113ec946082fc005210e59c5 Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8 Content-Transfer-Encoding
```

And so on. I checked for ways to get a clean body from that "multipart/alternative" but I couldn't find anything that helped me. Also there are several different Content-Types in the same body.

How do I get the clean body of the message, and do I have to handle it differently for differen content-types?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Email parsing is a whole subject in itself.  If you want to know everything about an email, you need a MIME Parser.   You can also interpret the bodystructure and try to find the correct subpart and decode that, which there are literally dozens of examples of here on Stackoverflow.

Comment: I'll have a look into that, thanks a lot for the quick answer.